# Unable to retrieve date info from Date Object, despite not being undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date

In typescript I have a `Trip` object, which contains a `startDate` property of type `Date`. When I print out the entire trip object, the date value is shown as : ""startDate": 2023-04-28T11:50:04.960Z,"

When I print out `trip.startDate`, it is returned as:

`Object { "nanoseconds": 493000000, "seconds": 1678036736, }`

but when I try print "trip.startDate?.getSeconds()" I get the error:

`TypeError: trip.startDate.getSeconds is not a function. (In 'trip.startDate.getSeconds()', 'trip.startDate.getSeconds' is undefined)`

I have also tried:

```
const dateString = trip.startDate?.toISOString();
if (dateString) {
  const date = new Date(dateString);
  const seconds = date.getSeconds();
  const dateString = date.toLocaleDateString();
  console.log(dateString);
}
```

and

```
const seconds = (trip.startDate as Date)?.getSeconds();
if (typeof seconds === 'number') {
  const date = new Date(seconds * 1000); // convert seconds to milliseconds
  const dateString = date.toLocaleDateString();
  console.log(dateString);
}
```

All to no avail.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `Object { "nanoseconds": 493000000, "seconds": 1678036736, }` does not look like a `Date`, even if `Trip` prints it out as one.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show a) the definition of `Trip` and b) the code where `startDate` gets populated. Use `console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2))` to show data so that we're not seeing a lot off browser console cruft.